# How to get the cfdiv to display under each line?

Tags: javascript, ajax, coldfusion

I have a table of records and the user can click on a name to show more detailed information about that certain record.  I have it set up with a  tag but each time the link is clicked it only shows up on the top of the page or the very first row.  Is there a way to get it to show under each name when it is click. Here is the code I have...

```
<table width="75%" border="1">
  <tr>
    <th>Student Name</th>
  </tr>
  <cfoutput query="Q">
  <tr>
    <td><a href="javascript:ColdFusion.navigate('detailedRecord.cfm?RLN=#RLN#','detail')">#Q.sln#, #Q.sfn#</a></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td><cfdiv id="detail"></cfdiv></td>
  </tr>
  </cfoutput>
</table>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since you are in a loop `<cfoutput query="Q">` you will need to make `detail` a *unique* identifier. As you have it written every iteration of your loop has the same id. Maybe just add the current row number to make it unique.

```
<table width="75%" border="1">
  <tr>
    <th>Student Name</th>
  </tr>
  <cfoutput query="Q">
  <tr>
    <td><a href="javascript:ColdFusion.navigate('detailedRecord.cfm?RLN=#RLN#','detail#Q.CurrentRow#')">#Q.sln#, #Q.sfn#</a></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td><cfdiv id="detail#Q.CurrentRow#"></cfdiv></td>
  </tr>
  </cfoutput>
</table>
```

Comment: Thank you so much this is exactly what I was looking for. :)   I was wondering do you know a quick way to have the div close when link is clicked again?

Comment: No, sorry I do not. I don't really use the built-in ColdFusion front-end tags like cfdiv. I use jQuery instead.

Comment: Okay thank you...I tried using jQuery at first but just couldn't figure out how to get it to work like that.

Comment: Can you give me a quick example or show me a place where I can find a good example on how to do this in jQuery?

Comment: Well I'm not sure exactly what you are trying to do but a [jQuery UI 
Accordion](http://jqueryui.com/accordion/) comes to mind.

Comment: Okay that is perfect and I love that example.  I tried using that but wasn't sure how to get it to work in each row of the records when a user clicks on a link.